# Done( ) из интерфейса Context, Golang

Tags: golang, context, golang-channels

Почему **Done()** из интерфейса **Context** возвращает **<-chan struct{}**?
Из какой горутины у нас что то записывается в этот канал и почему с этого канала возвращается пустая структура?

Если можно, ответ пообширней пожалуйста.

Comment: передача пустой структуры - самый оптимальный вариант.

Comment: а как еще можно оповестить клиента, что контекст завершился без передачи в канал? опишите как вы видите решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `Done()` интерфейса `Context` возвращает канал `<-chan struct{}` для того, чтобы обеспечить механизм для оповещения о завершении операции в асинхронной среде. Когда операция завершается или контекст отменяется, канал закрывается. При этом значение пустой структуры `struct{}` записывается в этот канал, чтобы сигнализировать о завершении операции.

Обычно, главная горутина начинает операцию, создавая контекст, и передает его во все создаваемые горутины, которые выполняют асинхронную работу. Если в какой-то момент операция должна быть завершена, главная горутина вызывает метод `cancel()` у контекста. Это приводит к закрытию канала `Done()` во всех горутинах, подписанных на этот контекст. Когда горутина получает закрытый канал, это означает, что операция должна быть завершена.

Значение пустой структуры `struct{}` используется в качестве сигнала о завершении операции, потому что оно не занимает память и может быть передано по каналу без накладных расходов. Таким образом, когда канал закрывается, это означает, что операция завершена, и это сигнализирует всем горутинам, которые ждут завершения операции, что они могут продолжить выполнение.

А каналы в Go являются механизмом коммуникации и синхронизации, особенно между горутинами. Они позволяют передавать значения между горутинами и синхронизировать их работу.

Answer (score 2):

Канал с пустой структурой - это распространнённая в Go идиома для уведомления о наступлении события без подробностей. То есть нужно пингануть ожидающие горутины, но при этом не требуется передавать какие-либо данные.

Для метода `Done` это как раз подходит. Нужно всего лишь сообщить, что контекст завершён, никакой дополнительной информации это событие не несёт. Поэтому этот метод возвращает `<-chan struct{}`

Теперь о том, кто пишет. Особенность именно этого метода заключается в том, что в него никто не пишет. Дело в том, что `case <-ctx.Done():` сработает не только когда в канал что-то записано, но и когда канал закрывается. Посмотрите в исходный текст [`context.go`](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/master/src/context/context.go#463) - когда вызывается функция `CancelFunc`, которую возвращают конктесты `WithCancel`, `WithDeadline`, `WithTimeout`, внутри реализация контекста просто закрывает канал, ничего не записывая.